# How to rearrange mutiple <section> after taking position input of the same from user in HTML

Tags: html, css, input

For example I have three sections:

```
<section id="about">
<p>I'm the about section</p>
</section>

<section id="education">
<p>I'm the education section</p>
</section>

<section id="work">
<p>I'm the work section</p>
</section>
```

How can I rearrange these sections after taking position input for each section via HTML from the user?

Comment: So do you want to rearrange the sections after the user submitted the input or just when he types something in?

Comment: Where is the user going to input ? Can you give more explanation in brief??

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Yes, the user will submit input of each section's position, and then the sections will rearrange accordingly after taking the input.